# Can the Network Profiler in Android Studio be used to modify responses, headers, or status codes similar to Charles?

Tags: json, rest, android-studio, debugging, charles-proxy

let's say there is an api call like

```
"https://example.com/part?pid=212"
```

and the response is a json object like:

```
{
   "name":"Calvin",
   "flag" : true
}
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to use the Network Profiler in Android Studio to modify the response and change the value of the flag field to false. Essentially, I'd like to intercept and manipulate the response during testing/debugging using the Network Profiler. Is this functionality available in Android Studio's Network Profiler, similar to how it can be done using tools like Charles?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, the Network Profiler in Android Studio now includes a new tab called "Rules" that allows us to modify responses. To add a rule, follow these steps:

1. Go to `App Inspection` and select `Network Inspector`.
2. Open the `Rules` tab.
3. Click on the plus button to add a new rule.

[image: add a new rule]

So, if you want to replace a specific value, such as the "flag" field, Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

[image]

even you can utilize the built-in **regex** replace functionality in the Network Profiler by check the `.*Regex`

and then For example, you can use `("flag"\s*:\s*)true` to match the field with a value of `"true"` and Specify the replacement text, such as `$1false`, to replace the matched value with `"false"`. The `$1` represents the captured group from the regex pattern.

After applying the regex replace, the "flag" field in the response will be modified accordingly. This allows you to customize the response during testing or debugging within the Network Profiler.

check document [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/network-profiler).